# Where does `stack build` store generated executables?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm using multiple `stack.yaml` files to build against GHC 7.8 and 7.10. How do I set up my `PATH` to include the binaries for a specific `stack.yaml` file, e.g. `stack-7.8.yaml`?

Answer (score 11):

The `stack path --local-install-root` command solves this problem. E.g., to setup your path for the binaries from `stack --stack-yaml stack-7.8.yaml`, do

```
export PATH=$(stack --stack-yaml stack-7.8.yaml path --local-install-root):$PATH
```

Note: the `stack exec` command can also be used here, but I don't want to clutter my scripts with calls to `stack --stack-yaml stack-7.8.yaml exec <cmd>` instead of plain `<cmd>`.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question in the title, the executables are stored in a project-local `.stack-work` folder. For me, the full path from the project folder is `.stack-work/dist/e626a42b/build/{PROJECT_NAME}-exe`. Other executables, such as the test and bench executables, are also stored here, in `{PROJECT_NAME}-test` and `{PROJECT_NAME}-bench` respectively.